# How can I start multiple screen sessions automatically?

Tags: linux, bash, gnu-screen

I'm trying to build a command that launches `screen`, creates four sessions with different names, and run four different commands.

I know how to do this manually:

```
1. screen
2. ./command1 args
3. CTRL-A :sessionname Session 1
4. CTRL-A C
5. (GOTO 2)
```

Can I do this with a bash script or something? How would I do so?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`screen -dmS "$SESSION_NAME" "$COMMAND" "$ARGUMENTS"` will spawn a screen running `$COMMAND` in the background.

You can see active sessions with `screen -ls` and reattach with `screen -r "$SESSION_NAME"`.

Dead sessions can be killed with `screen -wipe`.

Comment: It gets the job done!

Comment: This command creates a new screen session for each command. It cannot be used to create a single screen session containing one window for each command (as the manual steps in the question do). Thus, it does not answer the question, and the `.screenrc` answer below should have been accepted instead.

Comment: is there any real advantage to multi-windows-one-session if all you do is want to cheaply keep something running in the background?

Answer (score 41):

To start multiple sessions automatically, set up a `.screenrc` file, a config file for screen. In it, you can create sessions, start programs, change the working dir etc. I use it to initialise my screen session.

Simple exampe for a .screenrc file:

```
# don't display the copyright page
startup_message off

# increase scrollback buffer size
defscrollback 10000

# create windows
screen -t TODO vim TODO.txt
chdir src
screen -t coding vim main.c
screen -t run
```

The `screen` commands above each create one screen session. `-t` sets the session's title; the rest of the line is the command to run and its parameters.

Thus, the first and second `screen` line start a session and launch `vim` inside. The third one just starts a session and drops you at a prompt. `chdir` changes the working directory for all subsequent sessions.

If you want to have multiple `.screenrc` files, just name them any way you want, and select one with `screen -c myscreenrc`.

Comment: Thanks to your answer, I was able to come up with a setup I wanted. I noticed that `~` doesn't work in the rc file, however `$HOME` does. Another thing I noted is that the screen command only supports simple (literal) arguments. Naturally, it's not a shell with all the fancy expansions etc. If these are needed, can just use, as an example, `screen -t "http-server" bash -c 'http-server --hostname $(hostname -s)'`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the d, m, S options together:

```
screen -Sdm s1
screen -Sdm s2
screen -Sdm s3
```

S : To create a screen

d : detach from a screen

m : To enforce creation of screen, regardless whether screen is called from within another screen or not.

Comment: Interesting, that you can write like this, instead of `screen -dmS s1` etc. I didn't know that, when grouping options, the one with an argument needn't be last.

Answer (score 0):

I have many cases where I need to open up a set of hosts for investigation or support. Because I only need these additional windows occasionally I decided to use a shell script rather than `.screenrc` approach.

for example in ~/bin/prod_support:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ ! -z "$STY" ]]; then
        screen -t "hosta" ssh hosta
        screen -t "hostb" ssh hostb
else
        echo "start up screen first"
fi
```

If run from a *non-screen* shell I get a reminder... if run from inside screen, it will add titled windows for each script run.