# init.d script with screen command does not work

Tags: linux, debian, shell

I wrote this simply start script:

```
SESSION_NAME="session1"
COMMAND="python /opt/aaa/manage.py runserver 192.168.1.1:4300"

case "$1" in
    start)
        screen -dmS "$SESSION_NAME" "$COMMAND" "$ARGUMENTS"
        echo "session1 started"
        ;;
    stop)
        echo "Stopping session1"
        screen -S session1 -X quit
        echo "."
        echo "session1 stopped"
        ;;
    restart)
        echo "Restarting session1"
        screen -S session1 -X quit
        echo "."
        screen -dmS "$SESSION_NAME" "$COMMAND" "$ARGUMENTS"
        echo "session1 has restarted"
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/session1 {start|stop|restart}"
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
exit 0
```

But If I run /etc/init.d/startscript.sh start, it does not work. Screen session does not run. Can you help me please?
Thank you for replies.

Comment: Add #!/bin/bash -x

Comment: Thanks, But I added it on the top of the script, but change is only that it writes contain of script to console as:                      + SESSION_NAME=session1
+ COMMAND='python /opt/aaa/manage.py runserver 192.168.1.1:4300'

Comment: Did you try `/usr/bin/screen` and `/usr/bin/python` (or wherever these executables are)?

Comment: @nickie thanks but it is the same, it does not work...

Answer (score 0):

The problems with services are user and tty.

An alternate way to have screen run at bootup is to have the user login automatically and then launch screen with a preconfigured set of windows and commands in '~/.screenrc'

Reattach to that screen at login.

Comment: Thanks, can you give me any example with edit screenrc for my case please?

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I see your screen not starting is because of an error in the python command.
To identify the problem the script command may help you. It will write the output to a log file that you will be able to read.

Here is an improved version of the script, with the information I usually add in my scripts:

```
#!/bin/sh
NAME=session1
SCRIPTNAME=/etc/init.d/$NAME
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
SESSION_NAME="session1"
COMMAND="python /opt/aaa/manage.py runserver 192.168.1.1:4300"
LOGPATH="/var/tmp/session1.log"

case "$1" in
    start)
        screen -dmS "$SESSION_NAME" script -a --flush -c "$COMMAND" $LOGPATH
        echo "session1 started"
        ;;
    stop)
        echo "Stopping session1"
        screen -S session1 -X quit
        echo "."
        echo "session1 stopped"
        ;;
    restart)
        echo "Restarting session1"
        screen -S session1 -X quit
        echo "."
        screen -dmS "$SESSION_NAME" script -a --flush -c "$COMMAND" $LOGPATH
        echo "session1 has restarted"
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: $SCRIPTNAME {start|stop|restart}" >&2
        exit 2
        ;;
esac
exit 0
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didn´t create session1.log... :-(

Comment: Just brainstorming:
1/ do you have `script`installed?
2/ when you type the exact python command you have in your start script does it run correctly?
3/ do you have the text "session1 started" printed when you use the command?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with your `$COMMAND` variable.  The command name should be the `python` executable, the rest is arguments.  But, if you put it in quotes, `screen` thinks that the command's name is the whole string and looks for an executable with that name.

Try this:

```
COMMAND="/usr/bin/python /opt/aaa/manage.py runserver 192.168.1.1:4300"

case "$1" in
    start)
        screen -dmS "$SESSION_NAME" $COMMAND
        echo "$SESSION_NAME started"
        ;;
    ...
```

i.e., without the quotes surrounding `$COMMAND` and without the (unnecessary) `$ARGUMENTS` variable.  This should work.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have used this script, but I removed command for new window - [How can I start new window in the same screen session automatically?](https://superuser.com/questions/667395/how-can-i-start-new-window-in-the-same-screen-session-automatically)

Comment: This is not an answer --- I don't know what it is.  If it's a follow-up question and as this is your question to begin with, why don't you edit your original question?  Moreover, did you try the answers provided so far?  Do they work or fail for you?

Comment: Originnaly I had thought that I make it different - as one screen with windows. But after I had decided to do it with separete sessions. I created my script, that does not work. But answers that were posted here didn´t help me, so I tried moddify script from my last question. Now it works correctly.